# Operand data type varchar is invalid for avg operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep getting the above error message

> "Operand data type varchar is invalid for avg operator"

Can anyone fix it for me? PLEASE

```
WITH Average -- Calculating Mean
AS (
    SELECT avg(convert(VARCHAR(5), DateDiff(s, [ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME], [COMPLETE_DATE_TIME]) / 3600) + ':' + convert(VARCHAR(5), DateDiff(s, [ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME], [COMPLETE_DATE_TIME]) % 3600 / 60) + ':' + convert(VARCHAR(5), (DateDiff(s, [ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME], [COMPLETE_DATE_TIME]) % 60))) AS Average
    FROM [CLERKS]
    WHERE [ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME] >= DATEADD(dd, - 30, getdate() - 1)
    )
    ,data
AS (
    SELECT cast(ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME AS DATE) AS Attendance_Date
        ,avg(convert(VARCHAR(5), DateDiff(s, [ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME], [COMPLETE_DATE_TIME]) / 3600) + ':' + convert(VARCHAR(5), DateDiff(s, [ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME], [COMPLETE_DATE_TIME]) % 3600 / 60) + ':' + convert(VARCHAR(5), (DateDiff(s, [ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME], [COMPLETE_DATE_TIME]) % 60))) AS Arr_Com
    FROM [Clerks]
    WHERE [ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME] >= DATEADD(dd, - 30, getdate() - 1)
    GROUP BY cast(ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME AS DATE)
    )
SELECT a.Attendance_Date
    ,a.Arr_Com
    ,c.Average
    ,abs(a.Arr_Com - b.Arr_Com) AS MR
FROM data a
LEFT JOIN data b ON cast(a.Attendance_Date AS DATETIME) = cast(b.Attendance_Date AS DATETIME) + 1
CROSS JOIN Average c
ORDER BY a.Attendance_Date
GO
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What are you trying to do with `avg(convert(VARCHAR(5)`? why would you average a string?

Comment: @Momoosa . . . . This is clearly SQL Server, so I removed the MySQL tag.   The error is really obvious *and intentional*.  I am baffled by what you really want.  You should probably delete this question and ask a new question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: nothing is intentional.. im trying to get the time difference between [Arrival Date] and [Complete Date]  in time format HH:mm:ss but i need a daily average of the difference

Comment: So first of all average the seconds. And then once you've got the average seconds worry about formatting that as `HH:mm:ss`.. Might the average be more than a day?

Comment: (avg(datediff(Second,[ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME],[COMPLETE]))) as Average

where do i stick the formatting code?

Comment: **if** the average is always less than a day you can do `cast(dateadd(second,(avg(datediff(Second,[ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME],[COMPLETE]))),0) as time)` but this will be incorrect for time spans > 24 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem is that the implementation is incorrect. You don't want to average timestamps (5h:3m:20s), but durations.

Hence, you need to calculate the duration in the smallest denominator, in your case seconds, calculate the average in seconds, by using the AVG() function and then formatting that result to look like hh:mm:ss.

Your code should look like:

```
;WITH Average -- Calculating Mean
AS (
    SELECT AVG(DateDiff(s, [ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME], [COMPLETE_DATE_TIME])) as Average
    FROM [CLERKS]
    WHERE [ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME] >= DATEADD(dd, - 30, getdate() - 1)
    )
    ,data
AS (
    SELECT cast(ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME AS DATE) AS Attendance_Date
        , AVG(DateDiff(s, [ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME], [COMPLETE_DATE_TIME])) as Arr_Com
    FROM [Clerks]
    WHERE [ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME] >= DATEADD(dd, - 30, getdate() - 1)
    GROUP BY cast(ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME AS DATE)
    )
SELECT
    Attendance_Date
    , Arr_Com
    , Average
    , avg(convert(VARCHAR(5), MR / 3600) + ':' + convert(VARCHAR(5), MR % 3600 / 60) + ':' + convert(VARCHAR(5), MR % 60))) AS MR
FROM (
    SELECT a.Attendance_Date
        ,a.Arr_Com
        ,c.Average
        , abs(a.Arr_Com - b.Arr_Com) AS MR
    FROM data a
    LEFT JOIN data b ON cast(a.Attendance_Date AS DATETIME) = cast(b.Attendance_Date AS DATETIME) + 1
    CROSS JOIN Average c
    ) tmp
ORDER BY Attendance_Date
```

Comment: Sorry the MR column is perfectly fine.. its the Average column i need in the time format

Comment: @Momoosa Oh, okay, I missed that. I was in a hurry to reply and get back to work. Glad it worked out.